# my snake gameobject does not appear in Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

[my snake is a prefab and each tail, head, body have a sprite render component(https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7xAD.png)

This is my first post! I am new so I did not try much, but I never had a problem like this with my two other games. I just want the snake to appear in game. All help is welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: because your camera isnt pointing at it (as can be seen in the completely blue screen it represents)